# Reading Synthetic Aperture Radar raster images using python

Tags: python, gdal, remote-sensing, radar

Is it possible to read and modify Synthetic Aperture Radar raster images using python? `gdal` is not able to understand their `Type` which is `Binary (application/octet-stream)`. One can find sample radar images [here](http://www.alos-restec.jp/en/staticpages/index.php/service-sampledata-03).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the images works with the [gdal palsar driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_palsar.html) and therefore also in Python. You have to make sure to point gdal to the *VOL* file so it works.

```
>>> palsar = gdal.Open("D:\Downloads\psr_fbs15\PSR_FBS15\VOL-ALPSRP150170690-H1.5_UA")
>>> pal_arr = palsar.ReadAsArray()
>>> type(pal_arr)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Saving in that format won't work since it is read-only. You can however save your modified image in any other format gdal provides - e.g. GeoTiff.

Comment: Perfect @Kersten, Thx. Although I have few more queries but will give google search a try before asking you.

Comment: Happy to help. Questions that haven't been answered before are always welcome on GIS SE.